# Virial theorem confusion

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

Virial theorem says that $E_{t} = -\frac{E_{P}}{2}$ however this says that lets say for 2 gas molecules(Ne) the kinetic energy due to temperature a molecule of $Ne$ at 0K will have the same energy with a $Ne$ molecule at 300K which obviously isnt correct.So what is going on here?

Comment: The theorem implies the average values and does not say what you say it says. It is your false implication.

Comment: It's extremely poorly worded but what I think is being asked (but am not sure) is "Given there are no interparticle interactions in an ideal gas such as Neon doesn't the virial theorem predict the kinetic energy to be zero at all temperatures?" Which is actually a slightly subtle point. If that is the case and the poster clarify I'll provide an answer.

Comment: @IanBush yes thats what I am asking.

Comment: Kinetic and potential energy of electrons, on which the VT applies,  is non-zero at 0 K.  Non-zero is also kinetic and potential energy of Ne atoms in solid Ne matrix at 0 K (zero point quantum oscillations)

Comment: @Volpina Please make your question more clear, taking into account the comments. Also, check English, formatting etc. See the help pages for more information.

Comment: Also, why are you considering 2 atoms? And why do you write molecules of Ne instead of atoms (technically correct to say molecules but more accurate to write atom)? For formatting; use \$ \ce{Ne} \$ to show $\ce{Ne}$ (format a chemical formula). Use \$ \pu{0 K} \$ to show $ \pu{0 K} $ (format a quantity).

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments I am taking the question to mean "Given there are no interparticle interactions in an ideal gas doesn't the Virial theorem predict the kinetic energy to be zero at all temperatures?" Hopefully the original poster will edit the question to improve the wording so I can delete this clarification.

The short answer is "because of the externally applied pressure". The longer answer below follows [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/02%3A_Review_of_Newtonian_Mechanics/2.11%3A_Virial_Theorem)

Firstly you have incorrectly stated the Virial theorem. As noted in the comments it applies to *averages* of the energies, but over and above that the form you have is for a very specific particle interaction, an inverse square law such as Coulomb's law or gravity. This is discussed in the link above and is clearly not appropriate for an idea gas! The general form of the Virial Theorem is
$$
\langle T\rangle = - {1 \over 2} \left\langle \sum_i {\bf F_i}\cdotp{\bf r_i} \right\rangle
$$

where $T$ is the total kinetic energy of the particles, ${\bf F_i}$ is the force on particle i, ${\bf r_i}$ is the position of particle i and the angled brackets indicate averages (note to poster: you really should define any symbols you use)

Now we know the average kinetic energy from kinetic theory, or equipartition of energy, or whatever is your favourite method:
$$
\langle T \rangle = { 3 \over 2 } NkT
$$

where $N$ is the number of particles, $T$ is the temperature and $k$ is Boltzmann's constant.

What about the RHS of the Virial Thorem? Well naively in the ideal gas model there are no interparticle interactions, so all the forces are zero, so the RHS is zero, so how can the Virial theorem be obeyed?

What is being missed is while all the interparticle forces are zero, these are not the only forces on the particles; the particles also interact with what in Chemistry is usually called the "wall" containing the gas, so establishing the pressure. And this interaction with the wall will causes forces on the particles, so the RHS above is *not* zero due to the confinement of the gas.

To procede it is better to think not of a real container in which the gas is being held, but an external pressure that confines the gas; at equilibrium the internal pressure of the gas will equal the external confining pressure. Thus as the external pressure causes a force per unit area, and as this pressure will equal the internal pressure caused by the particles we can write
$$
d{\bf F_i}=-{\bf \hat{n}}PdA
$$

where $P$ is the (external) pressure, $dA$ is an element of area, and ${\bf \hat{n}}$ is a unit vector normal to the containing surface. Hence, using the divergence theorem
$$
- {1 \over 2} \left\langle \sum_i {\bf F_i}\cdotp{\bf r_i} \right\rangle =
{P \over 2} \int {\bf \hat{n}} \cdotp r_i dA = {P \over 2}\int {\bf \nabla } \cdotp {\bf r_i} dV = {{3}\over{2}}PV
$$

Hence using equating the two sides in the Virial equation and cancelling the ${{3}\over{2}}$ constants one gets
$$
NkT=PV
$$

which is simply the ideal gas law, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The Virial theorem can be derived only when there is an interaction between each and every pair of 'particles' in a gas, i.e. between atoms and/or molecules. The particles could even be dust or stars. In the case of an ideal gas the only interaction is that due to gravity, in real molecules dispersion forces in the general sense will also exist.

With an inverse square force (such as gravity) the Virial Theorem has the form $2E_K+V=0$ where $E_K$ is the kinetic energy and $V$ the total potential energy. The potential terms are sometimes called the 'Virial of Claussius'.

If your particles are in space and there is a cloud then the Virial theorem will apply and can be used to determine if such vast clouds are stable or not.

In a gas in the lab the interaction has three parts, the forces on collision, those due to intermolecular forces and also due to collisions with  walls containing the gas. Collisions with the wall introduces the pressure and volume and so the total kinetic energy $\sum mv^2/2$ becomes  equal to $3pV/2$ plus any intermolecular interactions. As the average kinetic energy is also $3/2k_BT$, where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant and $T$ the temperature then $nk_BT=pV$ + intermoleculear energy and the connection to an ideal gas is clear.   The kinetic theory of gasses thus shows that the pressure comes from the kinetic energy of motion of the particles plus a small contribution from the intermolecular forces.